# Не отображаются страницы wordpress

Tags: wordpress

(локальный сайт)

Я нажимаю на добавить страницу в админке wordpress, пишу заголовок , странница создана на неё можно перейти , но она не отображается в теме какую бы я тему не ставил(темы не создавал ничего нового в wordpress не вносил).

Comment: Настройки - Постоянные ссылки - Сохранить

Comment: Не помогает не знаю что делать уже